# How to pass string from another thread into an Data Received Event Args in C# WinForms

Tags: multithreading, events

I need some help with my project.

I have a main method which start a cmd process and redirects output onto event handler.

```
private void RunBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.process.StartInfo.FileName = sMasterBATname;
        this.process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        this.process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        this.process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        this.process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(StandardOutputHandler);
        this.process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        this.process.Start();
        this.process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }
```

CMD process runs number of exe files and everything would be fine but some of the exe output is redirected onto a text file(">>" command) and therefore is not handled by my event.

```
public void StandardOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
       if (outLine.Data != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(outLine.Data))
        {

          if (outLine.Data.Contains(">>"))
            {
                string[] commandLine = outLine.Data.Split('>');
                this.logFileFullPath = commandLine[1];
                this.logFileFullPath = this.logFileFullPath.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
                string[] split = logFileFullPath.Split('\\');
                this.logFileName = split[6];
                this.path = split[0] + "\\" + split[1] + "\\" + split[2] + "\\" + split[3] + "\\" + split[4] + "\\" + split[5];

                BatchRun.LogMonitor(this.logFileName,this.path) //this class will run on different thread 

           else
           {
               //validate content of received data
           }
            }
        }
    }
```

Both methods above are located in partial class.

Log Monitor which will run on separate thread and will perform a loop to check for any updates to the text/log file as per below which is based on [Tail like program](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/7568/tail-net):

```
public class Monitor
 {
     public LogMonitor(string LogName, string LogPath)
       {

          using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(LogName,
                 FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
           {
            //start at the end of the file
            long lastMaxOffset = reader.BaseStream.Length;

              while (true)
              {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

                //if the file size has not changed, idle
                if (reader.BaseStream.Length == lastMaxOffset)
                    continue;

                //seek to the last max offset
                reader.BaseStream.Seek(lastMaxOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                //read out of the file until the EOF
                string line = "";
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(line);

                //update the last max offset
                lastMaxOffset = reader.BaseStream.Position;
              }
           }
}
```

My issue is that I have no idea how to pass a line variable, each time a new line has been appended to the log, from LogMonitor method onto StandardOutputHandler so I can validate content of the log file the same way and act accordingly.

If someone could use my code and paste an answer that would be awesome. OR maybe someone can suggest a better way of achieving my goal?

I have only been using C# for 2 months so don't have great understanding of the evens etc...

Comment: Do I have to use delegates? If so how to adopt it as I'm not too sure I understand them correctly. Any suggestion will be great. Thanks

Comment: No answers so I'm guessing it cannot be done??

Comment: Surely there is a way to achieve it. HELP PLEASE.

Comment: So no one is able to help me?????